# Prisma query engine not found on mac M1

Tags: node.js, apple-m1, prisma, darwin, query-engine

I'm having an issue with running Prisma in my project. Running `npx prisma generate` works, but then running my app I get:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:36466
4:29:05 PM web.1 |        throw new PrismaClientInitializationError(errorText, this.config.clientVersion);
4:29:05 PM web.1 |              ^
4:29:05 PM web.1 |  PrismaClientInitializationError: Query engine library for current platform "darwin" could not be found.
4:29:05 PM web.1 |  You incorrectly pinned it to darwin
4:29:05 PM web.1 |  This probably happens, because you built Prisma Client on a different platform.
4:29:05 PM web.1 |  (Prisma Client looked in "/Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/libquery_engine-darwin.dylib.node")
```

I've noticed that the `libquery_engine-darwin.dylib.node` file actually exists as `libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node`. My `schema.prisma` file includes:

```
generator client {
  provider       = "prisma-client-js"
  bindaryTargets = ["native", "darwin"]
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to generate the right query engine binary with `darwin` and not `darwin-arm64`, or have the clientVersion look for the latter.

Here's `npx prisma -v`:

```
prisma                  : 3.7.0
@prisma/client          : 3.7.0
Current platform        : darwin-arm64
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 8746e055198f517658c08a0c426c7eec87f5a85f (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli 8746e055198f517658c08a0c426c7eec87f5a85f (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-darwin-arm64)
Introspection Engine    : introspection-core 8746e055198f517658c08a0c426c7eec87f5a85f (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-darwin-arm64)
Format Binary           : prisma-fmt 8746e055198f517658c08a0c426c7eec87f5a85f (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-darwin-arm64)
Default Engines Hash    : 8746e055198f517658c08a0c426c7eec87f5a85f
Studio                  : 0.445.0
```

I'm running on a new M1 iMac. Any help would be so so appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had `bindaryTargets`. Should be `binaryTargets`. LMAO

Answer (score 2):

For me mac M2, its work with `darwin-arm64`

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "darwin-arm64"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my node to v14 from v16, which worked for me. I didn't have to set the binaryTarget property.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}
```